# How to get the value of a specific table field by knowing the id and the column?(SQLite)

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I try to read values out of my database, by looking for their `_id`.

```
private static  final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "database";
private static final String COL1 = "_id";
private static final String COL2 = "Name";

    public String getData(int id, String col){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT value FROM " + TABLE_NAME +" WHERE
 /* id = _id and col = COL2 */", null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the query a little bit.

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL1 + "=" + id
```

Replace it with the String you are passing to the method `rawQuery()`

above solution will work but this might not be the best way to use `rawQuery()` method, as we are not using it's second parameter `selectionArgs`. Please refer [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) for details.

So final solution will look something like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL1 + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
```